Foreign key in anylogic database becoming unresolved
I am developing the project proposed by Benjamin in his tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casVdmKC-S0. However, when I set the foreign keys in the db_conveyors table, the foreign keys are unresolved without a clear reason. Any thoughts why?
You can find here below soe screenshots
enter image description here
enter image description here

maybe simply try to rebuild the dbase  tables manually, maybe something internal broken

Else hover over the error: what does it say?

I saved the model and restarted anylogic. Probably you are right, something internally was broken. It appears that other people also had the same problem...but it seems fixed now
